# How to recover SOL sent to a token mint address that I created?

Tags: token, mint, spl

I know it's a monkey brain mistake that I have sent some sol coins from phantom wallet to an SPL token address which I have created.

I created this token via Fluxbeam v1. I have been searching online for days but I couldn't find any solution.

The mint & authority has been revoked before sending those sol coins.

I also created openbook market id for it via dexlab if this help.

Is there a hope to recover those SOL coins I sent ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the token address?

Answer (score 1):

No. There’s no any way to close Mint account owned by old Token program.

You can use the new [token-extension program](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022#extensions) to create a mint which implements the mint close authority.

Comment: Hi boss, can I upgrade it somehow from v1 to token2022 to do this?

Comment: No you can’t. You can use token-2022 starting from your next mint so you can refund the rent.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i'm pretty sure if you can fix this by transfering the funds from the token acc to your acc but the fee payer needs to be the your address.

Using the solana cli you would have to add --fee payer option

(This would work if you somehow can get the keypair of the token account)

Comment: I wish i had an idea how to do so, i used fluxbeam to generate the token. It's a lot of SOL otherwise i would move on